# Problem with nil element in load-path in Emacs 24.4

Tags: init-file, emacs24.4, load-path

I just installed Emacs 24.4 from source (on Ubuntu 14.04). I now get the following error when running Emacs:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("/[._]emacs\\.d/?\\'" nil nil)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

For debugging, I reduced my `~/.emacs` init file to:

```el
(setq debug-on-error t)
(add-to-list 'load-path nil)
```

Then the error occurs only when starting Emacs with two arguments, where the first argument is an option, for example `--no-splash`, and the second argument is a file name with a suffix, for example `a.txt`. Some other observations:

- If I remove the option (`--no-splash`) it works fine,
- if I remove the line `(add-to-list 'load-path nil)` it works fine,
- if I run with Emacs v. 24.3 it works fine,
- if I change `nil` to `"."`, in `~/.emacs` it works fine,
- if I remove the suffix from the file name, that is: changing `a.txt` to `a`, I get another error: `Args out of range: 0`.

**Edit** After adding `nil` to `load-path`, the variable looks like:

```el
(nil "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/site-lisp" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/site-lisp" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/vc" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/url" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/textmodes" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/progmodes" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/play" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/org" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/nxml" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/net" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/mh-e" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/mail" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/leim" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/language" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/international" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/gnus" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/eshell" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/erc" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/emulation" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/emacs-lisp" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/cedet" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/calendar" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/calc" "/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/obsolete")
```

According to the Emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html):

Variable: **load-path**

> The value of this variable is a list of directories to search when
>   loading files with load. Each element is a string (which must be a
>   directory name) or nil (which stands for the current working
>   directory).

Comment: Note for moderators: I tried to add a tag to my question for `commandline arguments`, but could not find any such tags.. Maybe it should be added by someone?

Comment: There is no such tag yet, therefore I went with `init` since this is about what happens before Emacs initialization is done.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you (on purpose) be trying to add `nil` to your `load-path`?  Unless I am mistaken, the purpose of using `add-to-list` is to add *something* to a list, instead of *nothing*.  And if Emacs looks to that list to decide which files to load and it encounters a `nil` value, wouldn't one naturally expect to see an error?  How could a `nil` value inside a `load-path` list be useful?

Comment: @lawlist I think `nil` stands for the current directory, see the reference in the last part of my question..

Comment: Thank you -- you are correct.  There is an admonishment in the documentation as follows:  *A list entry in load-path can also have the special value nil, which stands for the current default directory, but it is almost always a bad idea to use this. (If you find yourself wishing that nil were in the list, most likely what you really want is to use M-x load-file.)*:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html

Comment: @lawlist Thanks.. Yes it is probably a bad idea, but still it is not the correct behavior :) So it is probably a bug somewhere..

Comment: @Drew The bug has already been fixed for the next release. See http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Emacs source `startup.el` and has already been fixed for the next release of Emacs.. See http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19584 for more details..